# Python colorama: Colors not showing in txt file

Tags: python, colorama

I am using the python package `colorama`. When I redirect the output to standard output, it shows the colors. But when I redirect it to a .txt file, it doesn't show up the colors but shows a bunch of `ESC[*m` characters. I have tried using cat and less but nothing shows up the colors. Here is an example of how the txt file looks:

```
sample1  AFF4   protein_codingESC[31m   5:132216878-132219032   ESC[39m1748  Both annotated  16   73:sample2,81:sample2,88:sample,93:sample,95:27571P,100:sample05:sample,108:sample,111:sample,114:sample,120:sample20:sample,123:sample,128:95-0614-P,133:sampleESC[31mESC[32m,156:sample  ESC[39mESC[39m1.0:sample,1.0:sample.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:sample.0:95-1682-P,1.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:sample,1.0:95-0614-P,1.0:27571PESC[31mESC[32m,1.0:sample  ESC[39mESC[39mCHOPS syndrome    Autosomal dominant
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: txt files are *plain text*. They don't support colour or any other kind of formatting. The `ESC[` characters are called control sequences and instruct the terminal to print the text in different colours.

Comment: Is there a format I can write the output to so the colors are shown when I do less on it?

Comment: "producing colored *terminal* text", from the pypi Page.

Comment: Try using `less -R` when displaying the file.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thank you!! Can you please move this to the answer so I can accept it?